# SQL Script for creating test sample data from source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've created the script below to be able to quickly create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for other questions in general.

This script uses an original table and generates the following `PRINT` statements:

- `DROP` and `CREATE` a temp table with structure matching the original table
- `INSERT INTO` statement using examples from the actual data

I can just add the original table name into the variable listed, along with the number of sample records required from the table.  When I run it, it generates all of the statements needed in the Messages window in SSMS.  Then I can just copy and paste those statements into my posted questions, so those answering have something to work with.

I know that you can get similar results in SSMS through Tasks>Generate Scripts, but this gets things down to the minimal amount of code that's useful for posting here without all of the unnecessary info that SSMS generates automatically.  It's just a quick way to create a reproduced version of a simple table with actual sample data in it.

Unfortunately the one scenario that doesn't work is if I run it on very wide tables.  It seems to fail on the last `STRING_AGG()` query where it's building the `VALUES` portion of the `INSERT`.  When it runs on wide tables, it returns `NULL`.

Any suggestions to correct this?

EDIT: I figured out the issue I was having with `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` columns and revised the query below.  Also included an initial check to make sure the table actually exists.

```
/* ---------------------------------------
-- For creating minimal reproducible examples
-- based on original table and data,
-- builds the following statements
--    -- CREATE temp table with structure matching original table
--    -- INSERT statements based on actual data
--
-- Note: May not work for very wide tables due to limitations on 
--         PRINT statements
*/ ---------------------------------------

DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'testTable', -- original table name HERE
        @recordCount INT = 5,                   -- top number of records to insert to temp table
        @buildStmt NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @insertStmt NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @valuesStmt NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @insertCol NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @strAgg NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @insertOutput NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName))
BEGIN

    -- build DROP and CREATE statements for temp table from original table
    SET @buildStmt = 'IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#' + @tableName + ''') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #' + @tableName + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) +
               'CREATE TABLE #' + @tableName + ' (' + CHAR(10)

    SELECT @buildStmt = @buildStmt + ' ' + C.[Name] + ' ' +
                T.[Name] +
                CASE WHEN T.[Name] IN ('varchar','varchar','char','nchar') THEN '(' + CAST(C.[Length] AS VARCHAR) + ') ' ELSE ' ' END +
                'NULL,' + CHAR(10)
    FROM sysobjects O
    JOIN syscolumns C ON C.id = O.id
    JOIN systypes T ON T.xusertype = C.xusertype
    WHERE O.[name] = @TableName
    ORDER BY C.ColID

    SET @buildStmt = SUBSTRING(@buildStmt,1,LEN(@buildStmt) - 2) + CHAR(10) + ')' + CHAR(10)
    PRINT @buildStmt

    -- build INSERT INTO statement from original table
    SELECT @insertStmt =  'INSERT INTO #' + @tableName + ' (' +
        STUFF ((
            SELECT ', [' + C.[Name] + ']'
            FROM sysobjects O
            JOIN syscolumns C ON C.id = O.id
            WHERE O.[name] = @TableName
            ORDER BY C.ColID
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
        +')' 

    PRINT @insertStmt

    -- build VALUES portion of INSERT from data in original table
    SELECT @insertCol = STUFF ((
            SELECT '''''''''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200),' +
            '[' + C.[Name] + ']' + 
            ')+'''''',''+' 
            FROM sysobjects O
            JOIN syscolumns C ON C.id = O.id
            JOIN systypes T ON T.xusertype = C.xusertype
            WHERE O.[name] = @TableName
            ORDER BY C.ColID
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
    SET @insertCol = SUBSTRING(@insertCol,1,LEN(@insertCol) - 1) 

    SELECT @strAgg = ';WITH CTE AS (SELECT TOP(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@recordCount) + ') * FROM ' + @tableName + ') ' +
                     ' SELECT @valuesStmt = STRING_AGG(CAST(''' + @insertCol + ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),''),  ('') ' +
                     ' FROM CTE' 
    EXEC sp_executesql @strAgg,N'@valuesStmt NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @valuesStmt OUTPUT

    PRINT 'VALUES (' +REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@valuesStmt,1,LEN(@valuesStmt) - 1),',)',')') + ')'

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Table does NOT exist'
END
```

Comment: If it isn't a question it doesn't belong on SO, no matter how well-intentioned. You can, however, easily make it one: "how do I ...." and then self-answer with your script. (Some people frown on self-answered questions on principle, but they're certainly allowed. They should, of course, still abide by the other criteria of not being subjective, unfocused etcetera.)

Comment: Updated to a question for help with known loopholes I've noticed in my script.  Thanks.

Comment: I love the spirit behind this tbh. I'm a total noob to SQL though and honestly wouldn't know where to start with your code. Any chance you could include super simple instructions for how to use it for noobs like me? I.e. 1) copy script below and put it somewhere..., 2) copy data it creates and do ... with it

Comment: @C.Robin Open up SQL Management Studio and the database server in question.  Select the database which the table is in, then open a new query window.  Copy and paste the code above and change the `@tableName` value from "testTable" to whatever your actual table name is.