# Exclude an item only when there are multiple entries

Tags: sql, count

I have a table of data with policy information:

```
Row  PolicyNumber    Member ID    PolicyName
1    1234            789          Main
2    1265            789          Travel
3    1523            541          Travel
4    6778            374          Main
5    5821            123          Main
6    8763            123          Travel
```

I want to count the number of distinct MEMBERID's within each policynumber.  However, some members have more than one policynumber because some members have a travel policy and a main policy.

So I want SQL to check for a count of `POLICYNUMBER` by `MEMBERID` first, and where the POLICYNUMBER count is greater than one, to bring only the policy numbers where the `POLICYNAME` is not like '%travel%'

But, if the member ONLY has one policy, I want SQL to include that policy even if it's travel.

So in my sample data:

```
Member 789 would be counted against policy 1234 but not 1265
Member 541 would be counted against policy 541
Member 374 would be counted against policy 6778
Member 123 would be counted against policy 5821 but not 8763
```

Desired result would be a table of two columns, PolicyNumber and the distinct count of MemberId associated to that policy.

How do I write the syntax?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: I can't provide sample data, desired result is table of two columns, policy number and count of members associated to that policy, and I don't know what a database tag is.

Comment: @Jemma no one expects *actual* production data you certainly coud provide *sample* data - ie fabricated data that illustrates what you have and what you expect.

Comment: @Jemma I have a script [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67094822/sql-script-for-creating-test-sample-data-from-source-table) that will produce the kind of scripted table schema and sample data that is being asked for here.  This will work for simple tables in SQL Server.  You can try this out and it should hopefully show you the kind of data that's being requested.

Comment: Thanks @WAMLeslie but I'm a total noob at SQL and I just don't know where to start with doing this. 
I basically have three columns I care about: [POLICYNUMBER], [MEMBER ID] (count) AND [POLICYNAME].
I want to count distinct [MEMBERID] against [POLICYNUMBER] but I want SQL to first check count distinct of [POLICYNAME] and where count (distinct [POLICYNAME]) > 2 then to just look at any [POLICYNUMBER] where [POLICYNAME] not like '%TRAVEL%'. But, if count(distinct [POLICYNAME] = 1 then 'Travel' is allowed to be included.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using multiple having conditions -

```
SELECT Member_ID, COUNT(*)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 GROUP BY Member_ID
HAVING COUNT(PolicyName) = 1
       OR COUNT(CASE WHEN PolicyName NOT LIKE '%travel%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ankit this makes sense - except the final closed parenthesis is kicking off. Says incorrect syntax.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this Monday - I really appreciate it :-)